# Execute shell commands through an html button(onclick )

Tags: html, linux, shell, button, onclick

I am trying to execute shell commands or shell script through `onclick` function in HTML button. For eg:

```
<button type="button" onclick="/path/to/name.sh">Click Me!</button>
```

Is there any way to do so or some other way around?

Comment: NodeJS is your friend then.

Comment: what do you mean @hek2mgl man .I am working on this for last 2 days.have also tried my handson php for server side scripting .but nothing worked man. i just need suggestion to achive this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think i have not posted this question for people to check whether the question is grammatically correct or any oother characteristics like that.I was stuck in this problem for quiet long so just looking for possible solutions.right.@hek2mgl

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked. Check the below link.

[Run a shell script with an html button](https://superuser.com/questions/292818/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button)

The method posted may be feasible with some tweaks in Apache, but it is not the most common way of running a shell script.

If you are using PHP, you can use system(), exec(), popen(), etc... and the path to your file ex:

`exec('/path/to/file.sh');`

You need to make sure of two things first:

1. The users you are running as has the proper permissions to execute the shell file.
2. exec() is not listed as a disabled function in the php.ini (normally, some hosting providers disable them for security issues).